Laptop is not able to load Ubuntu
I have a Dell G15 laptop (16GB RAM, 1TB SSD, NVIDIA RTX 350). I removed Windows and installed Ubuntu. The installation was successful without any issue, but when I started my laptop it was not able to boot Ubuntu (the screen was stuck at the Dell logo) for more than 15 minutes. I forced shutdown started it again, and the second time it booted as expected.
This is happening every single time. First time it is not able to boot, but it works normally the second time.


That's a strange one. The thing that comes to mind first is that you check your boot settings in the BIOS.
